# Vue2 pass vuex store data to directive using apollo

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuex, apollo, vue-composition-api

I have this footer defined in my store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    pages: [],
    footer: null,
    loading: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    setPages: (state, payload) => (state.pages = payload),
    setFooter: (state, payload) => (state.footer = payload),
    setLoading: (state, payload) => (state.loading = payload),
  },
  actions: {
    getPages: ({ commit }) => {
      commit("setLoading", true);
      apolloClient
        .query({ query: pageCollection })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          commit("setPages", data.pageCollection.items);
          commit("setLoading", false);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          commit("setLoading", false);
        });
    },
    getFooter: ({ commit }) => {
      apolloClient
        .query({ query: footerCollection })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          console.log(data.footerCollection.items[0]);
          commit("setFooter", data.footerCollection.items[0]);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    },
  },
  getters: {
    pages: (state) => state.pages,
    footer: (state) => state.footer,
    loading: (state) => state.loading,
  },
  modules: {},
});
```

In my footer, I do this:

```
import {
  computed,
  defineComponent,
  getCurrentInstance,
} from "@vue/composition-api";

import { content } from "@/directives";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "TheFooter",
  directives: {
    content,
  },
  setup() {
    const instance = getCurrentInstance();
    const store = instance.proxy.$store;
    store.dispatch("getFooter");

    const footer = computed(() => store.getters.footer);

    return { footer };
  },
});
```

As you can see, I am passing the footer to the component. From here I can do something like `{{ footer }}` to see the json response. But I would like to pass (part of) the footer to a directive.
I tried doing this:

```
<div v-content="footer" v-if="footer"></div>
```

And inside my directive, I console log the footer, like this:

```
import { DirectiveBinding } from "vue/types/options";

export const content = {
  bind(el: HTMLElement, binding: DirectiveBinding): void {
    const { value } = binding;
    const openMarks = {
      bold: true,
      italic: true,
      underline: true,
    };
    console.log(value);
    // const html = parseHtmlString(value, openMarks);
    // console.log(html);
    // el.innerHTML = html;
  },
};
```

But what I get is an observable instead of an object.

[image]

How can I unwrap the observable so I can parse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you want to see your footer in a `console.log()`. Some browsers have a little better functionality with being able to read your observable objects, but the easy way is to wrap & unwrap it as JSON, so:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)));
```

Second, you're trying to output your footer as a directive, which is curious, and not the approach I would take. Instead, what if you made your footer its own component? I think it could work and be cleaner, and probably end up being more versatile for you.

```html
<my-app-footer />
```

```
<template>
  <div v-if="footer" v-html="footer">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  computed {
    ...mapGetters(["footer"]);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering; the reason it isn't a component is that it's not the footer I am trying to render, there is a json array inside it (and many other responses) that needs converting to html (it's a rich text editor that has strange markup in it) so that it can be assigned to inner html